# Using StanfordParser to get typed dependencies from a parsed sentence

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

Using NLTK's StanfordParser, I can parse a sentence like this:

```
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = 'C:\jars' 
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = 'C:\jars'  
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] ='C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath' 
parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path="C:\jars\englishPCFG.ser.gz")
sentences = parser.parse(("bring me a red ball",)) 
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence
```

The result is:

```
Tree('ROOT', [Tree('S', [Tree('VP', [Tree('VB', ['Bring']),
Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['a']), Tree('NN', ['red'])]), Tree('NP',
[Tree('NN', ['ball'])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])])
```

How can I use the Stanford parser to get typed dependencies in addition to the above graph? Something like:

1. root(ROOT-0, bring-1)
2. iobj(bring-1, me-2)
3. det(ball-5, a-3)
4. amod(ball-5, red-4)
5. dobj(bring-1, ball-5)

Comment: Hi Yarik, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've tried to make the wording of your question and title more clear.

Answer (score 6):

NLTK's StanfordParser module doesn't (currently) wrap the tree to Stanford Dependencies conversion code. You can use my library [PyStanfordDependencies](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyStanfordDependencies), which wraps the dependency converter.

If `nltk_tree` is `sentence` from the question's code snippet, then this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import StanfordDependencies

# Use str() to convert the NLTK tree to Penn Treebank format
penn_treebank_tree = str(nltk_tree) 

sd = StanfordDependencies.get_instance(jar_filename='point to Stanford Parser JAR file')
converted_tree = sd.convert_tree(penn_treebank_tree)

# Print Typed Dependencies
for node in converted_tree:
    print('{}({}-{},{}-{})'.format(
            node.deprel,
            converted_tree[node.head - 1].form if node.head != 0 else 'ROOT',
            node.head,
            node.form,
            node.index))
```

Comment: hello when I tried converting nltk tree to ptb,with the same, it gave a error like "ValueError: Bad exit code from Stanford CoreNLP"

Comment: @SnehaPVS, thanks for the note. Please file an issue at https://github.com/dmcc/PyStanfordDependencies/issues with more details.

Comment: Is there an alternate way to convert the nltk tree to PTB format

Comment: tree.pprint()  will work as well, but str(tree) should be fine (at least for the newest versions of NLTK and possibly older ones too).

Comment: If you are using `NLTK` and the `StanfordParser` wrapper, then after doing a `.raw_parse` you will get a iterable object, which you can convert to list via the `list` command. If `tree_list` is the list you get, then the root tree is the first element of: `tree_list[0]`. And to get the `penn_treebank_tree` variable above, you would use `tree_list[0].pformat()`. If you have more than one line of text, you might need to remove the extra `\n` and extra whitespaces before calling `sd.convert_tree`.